# Is it possible to enable a process to remain active during Windows sleep mode?

Tags: windows, networking, process, sleep

While the majority of processes are sleeping, can a selection of them continue to operate normally?

Comment: why the down-votes without comments?

Comment: Certain tasks might be possible *if* your (Media Center) PC supports **Away Mode**. See my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/563036/138343) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If by "active" you mean running when in sleep mode, the answer is NO ..
- If you mean "active" when the computer wakes up again, the answer is YES.